# How to remove fastaddressbar?

Tags: firefox, malware

somehow I downloaded and installed spyware or malware. I do not know.
I know that if I write somethin in field where you put as a website link I get web engine results but not by google but fastaddressbar.. It is part of websearch toolbar. Most of them was blocked and added to quarantine by my antivirus comodo however I still do not know how restore fast search in firefox to get results from google. Please help :(

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to Programs and Features in the Control Panel and look for an entry there. Also, go to Firefox > Add-ons > Extensions and remove it if it is installed there. Source credit: http://www.pcrisk.com/removal-guides/6953-remove-fast-address-bar

Comment: yes but this is just a homepage, i dont want also see this malware site when i search any text inputting this into field with link. I made an arrow what I was talking about

Comment: Updated answer and included a link that may help.

Answer (score 0):

In the top bar, type `about:config`.  In the search bar on the page, type `browser.search.defaultenginename`.  Double-click the value that appears, and enter `Google` in the window that appears.  Click "OK" and restart Firefox.  Your search engine is now Google!

Comment: yes but after restart i have again this malware :/ no mather what I set there or just click `reset value`

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall it from Add/Remove Programs if it shows up there, then run [Malwarebytes Anti-Malware Free](http://www.malwarebytes.org) to clean your PC, and finally if it's still there, [reset Firefox](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/reset-firefox-easily-fix-most-problems) (be sure to read that entire page before doing it).

Comment: in add/remove programs was nothing which could be connected with this program, i tried spbybot but he doesn't help :/ I will try this Anit-Malware...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, it was useful for me: [How to reset the address bar so it would work as a Google Search bar again? | Firefox Support Forum](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/946403?&mobile=0)

> When you enter a search term in the Firefox location bar and press
>   Enter, Firefox will per default do a "I'm feeling lucky" Google search
>   and redirect you to the first result that matches your search term.
>   This behaviour can be changed by a number of add-ons. If you'd like to
>   restore the previous default behaviour, please follow these steps:
>
> - Enter about:config in the Firefox location bar and press Enter.
> - You should see a warning that making changes to the Firefox configuration can be potentially harmful to Firefox's integrity. Click
>     the I'll be careful, I promise button to continue.
> - In the Search box at the top, enter keyword as the search term. You should see a few remaining items, one of these is keyword.URL. It
>     should be bold.
> - Right-click on the keyword.URL setting and select Reset from the dropdown menu.

Comment: yes, but as I said few posts ago that after restart I have again the same settings with that ugly malware fastadressbar

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a program called **ADw Cleaner**. This program is very effective at removing annoying toolbars. I have used it in the past to get rid of the annoying Babylon toolbar amongst other addons, which it did, and also in very little time.

Click on **Download Now @BleepingComputer** at the following web address:

http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/adwcleaner/

I'm positive it will solve the problem.